# Set default value for struts 2 autocompleter

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-plugin

I have implemented a struts 2 autocompleter in which i have used a list of String like this -

```xml
<sj:autocompleter id="cityId"  
            cssClass="txtfield8"
                name="outlet.cityName" 
                list="cityList" 
        autoComplete="true" 
    forceValidOption="false" />
```

How can I set a default value for this, so that every time it loads, a default value will be shown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`value` attribute](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag#Attributes) as suggested by @Choatech:

> ```
> value   false   false   String   "Preset the value of input element."
> ```

The value specified, however, should be one of the keys listed in your `cityList`, not some random value.

If the value you want to use is an header one, like `Please choose a City...`, then consider using the

> [HTML5 `placeholder` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25605564/1654265).

Answer (score 2):

Just place your default value in the value argument.

```
<sj:autocompleter id="cityId" 
               value="" 
            cssClass="txtfield8" 
                name="outlet.cityName" 
                list="cityList" 
        autoComplete="false" 
    forceValidOption="false" />
```

Comment: turn autoComplete to false.